# Custom Log4J Appender

Tags: java

I have written a Custom Log4J Appender which is responsible for sending the log message to a third party service asynchronously. It is expected to be called every millisecond.

I ran FindBugs on this code, it didn't report anything unusual. But before releasing this code to production, how can I know if this code has any issues with it?

```
package com;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;

public class MyAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {

    public MyAppender() {

    }

    public void append(LoggingEvent event) {
        ArrayList<LoggingEvent> buffer = new ArrayList<LoggingEvent>();
        buffer.add(event);
        flushBuffer(buffer);
    }

    public void flushBuffer(ArrayList<LoggingEvent> buffer) {
        for (Iterator<LoggingEvent> i = buffer.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            try {
                LoggingEvent logEvent = (LoggingEvent) i.next();
                String messageRecievied = (String) logEvent.getMessage();
                //System.out.println(messageRecievied);

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean requiresLayout() {

        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: If you want a very simple check if whether your code has any issues then test it against this very simple checklist http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/05/code-smells.html Code smells As you gain experience with that you will find locationg code smells easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I don't think the `close()` method is following the contract, [from the javadoc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/AsyncAppender.html#close%28%29):

> It is a programming error to append to a closed appender.

Therefore, your `close()` method should be implemented like this:

```
@Override
public void close() {
    this.closed = true;
}
```

Note that `closed` is a protected field in `AppenderSkeleton`.

Then, change `append` to something like (add the `@Override` as well):

```
@Override
public void append(LoggingEvent event) {
    if (!this.closed) {
        ArrayList<LoggingEvent> buffer = new ArrayList<LoggingEvent>();
        buffer.add(event);
        flushBuffer(buffer);
    } else {
        // It is a programming error to append to a closed appender.
        throw new RuntimeException("Attempting to append to a closed Appender.");
    }
}
```

Next, does `flushBuffer` need to be `public`? It should probably be `private`.

Finally—and this is more of a nitpick—you don't need to declare the default constructor since it's empty and the compiler will create one for you. It'll make your code a little cleaner as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add source code comments. Why does the class exist? What does it do? What do each of the methods do? What are their pre- and post-conditions?

This code:

```
ArrayList<LoggingEvent> buffer = new ArrayList<LoggingEvent>();
```

Should be:

```
List<LoggingEvent> buffer = new ArrayList<LoggingEvent>();
```

Similarly:

```
public void flushBuffer(ArrayList<LoggingEvent> buffer) {
```

As:

```
public void flushBuffer(List<LoggingEvent> buffer) {
```

Next up:

```
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

Allow that Exception to bubble up:

```
public void flushBuffer(List<LoggingEvent> buffer) throws Exception {
```

But, be as specific as possible about the exception that can be thrown (i.e., if isn't Exception itself that is thrown, but a subclass, then opt to throw that subclass instead).